How about finally enabling syntax highlighting for RE.SE?
I would like to once again put forward this old proposal. Let's activate syntax highlighting for RE.SE.
Currently it is not enabled.

There are plenty of examples of Python code for helper scripts in answers, including Angr-related, IDAPython and Python-based GDB scripts
There are pieces of various scripting languages, such as obfuscated and deobfuscated Javascript code
Java would be useful for certain Ghidra-related Q&As (but it also has some Python integration as well)
There are several questions which attempt to correlate C/C++ source code to disassembly
There are plenty of questions and answers with pseudo code that could probably be syntax highlighted as C/C++
IDC, the original IDA scripting language is close enough to C/C++ to benefit from syntax highlighting
Tags for some of the above (and below): idapython, java, python, c++, javascript, c# and hexrays & decompilation (for C/C++ pseudo code)

Concrete examples

Bash & Python: this answer
Python: this Q&A, related to IDAPython
Bash: this answer
C/C++: this answer
Bash: this answer
C/C++: this answer (but also the question)
C/C++: this question
Python: this answer
Python: this question
Python: this question
C/C++ & Python: this Q&A
C/C++ pseudo code: this question
C/C++ pseudo code: this question
C/C++ with inline assembly: this question
C/C++ pseudo code: this question
Assembly: this question


For the record, JNat wrote in a comment over here, quote:

Have a discussion on Meta; once a consensus is reached, create a separate post for the actual request (pointing to the discussion and consensus) and [status-review] it as per this post. A CM will then evaluate your request and discuss next steps depending on their assessment.


Update 2023-02-21: put in the request now
Update 2023-03-02: it is now enabled


I enabled the following default languages for tags. This is mostly thought as a reference for now:

c++ -> lang-cpp
decompilation -> lang-c
c -> lang-c
idapython -> lang-py
python -> lang-py
java -> lang-java
javascript -> lang-js
c# -> lang-cs
idapro-sdk -> lang-cpp (debatable, but C++ is the better choice compared to C here)
gcc -> lang-cpp
struct -> lang-c
angr -> lang-py
delphi -> lang-pascal (no better match seems to exist)
lua -> lang-lua
php -> lang-php
mfc -> lang-cpp
idc -> lang-cpp (up for debate, we could also try lang-c, but this would also cover auto)
mssql -> lang-sql
go -> lang-golang
vba -> lang-vb
pykd -> lang-py
erlang -> lang-erlang


Yes.
Is there anything that has to be done to enable it, or is it just decision based? Why it wasn't done already?

It's a decision the community has to make. We need to provide proof that there is need (which I hope I did) and then need to gather enough votes so we can go to the community managers and ask them to enable it. I frankly don't know what the exact threshold is, because I doubt a lot of those frequenting the community also lurk on meta.RE.SE ...
